# Can any data be learned using polynomial logistic regression?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, logistic-regression

We know that a Taylor polynomial can approximate any smooth function. In binary logistic regression we're trying to fit a decision boundary to our data. But this decision boundary is not necessarily a function. It could be something like a circle $(x_1)^2 + (x_2)^2 = 1$, where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the features. You can't expect a polynomial to approximate a circle.

Is it true that we can approximate any decision boundary with logistic regression provided we use polynomial features of high enough degree? How to prove (or just show) it? And doesn't it contradict my first paragraph?

Comment: it seems you have already answered it. In general machine learning cannot learn mapping functions which have multiple different results for same input. There has to be unique results.

Comment: @NikosM., No, I didn't answer it, since the polynomial logistic regression indeed can come up with a circular decision boundary. That's why I am wondering whether it can approximate any kind of decision boundary.